# Burn [ftl] or make synonym of [freemarker]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The file extension of FreeMarker templates is `ftl`. I don't see the point of having an additional [freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freemarker) tag being its file extension ([ftl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ftl)). If it can't be burned, it should at least be a synonym IMO.

See for example: [how shall I store date into a variable without changing type of the date in freemarker ftl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800205/how-shall-i-store-date-into-a-variable-without-changing-type-of-the-date-in-free)

Comment: Seems reasonable. Did you check to make sure all the questions on the [tag:ftl] tag are about freemarker?

Comment: Yes, they all are currently

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I still see the ftl tag in the linked question. Is a synonym not instant?

Comment: I synonymized but didn't merge; not sure why I didn't merge, they're all about the same thing. Will fix

Comment: Hum..., mini-Note, sbd should review the Content of the [Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/freemarker/info) for that Tag (`/tags/ftl/info`), at least the "*we provide*" Section sounds like copied verbatim (or using the "P"-Word: plagiarized) from [somewhere else](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Note%2C+however%2C+that+we+provide+out-of-the-box+solutions+for+using+FreeMarker+as+the+view+component+of+Model+2+frameworks+%28e.g.+Struts%29%22) (...?), without any Attribution... :idea:

Comment: Sigh... Nuked both the wiki and excerpt. They're both overwhelmingly plagiarism. Feel free to replace with a non-plagiarized one

Comment: @Zoe, ah-ah, yep indeed, but *improving* the Tag Wiki and the Excerpt can *better* be done by "sbd" with Knowledge about the Tag/Technology, I don't know anything about it, not "my Tag"... :wink: